# When passing a prop into a class component my IntelliJ linter will not recognize this.props.propName

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

Is there a linter setting that I need to change or is there a step while passing the props that I am missing? The code works and the props are correctly getting passed in, but the underline warning is driving me crazy.

[image]

Comment: I've just dealt with this...for a long..long...long...long...time. I hope you get an answer.

Comment: do you have react typings (`@types/react` or similar) installed? if yes, try removing them - might be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29841